MSK connector failed to find class in MSK cluster with KRaft mode
I have a Kafka 3.7.x cluster using ZooKeeper mode which works well. Now I am trying new Kafak in KRaft mode:

However, for this Kafka cluster in KRaft mode, the same connector failed to start.

Here is full Kakfa Connector error log.
Note inside it has

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any
class that implements Connector and which name matches
com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector, available
connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=sink, typeName='sink',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector',
version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector',
version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector',
version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.7.1',
encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=connector, typeName='connector',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=sink, typeName='sink',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector,
name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector',
version='2.7.1', encodedVersion=2.7.1, type=source, typeName='source',
location='classpath'} ```


Both Kafka clusters are using same plugin which is a zip file with these jars. You can see snowflake-kafka-connector-2.2.2.jar which has com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector inside.

For these two Kafka clusters, the connector and plugin are using same cTerraform code meaning all parameters are same.
The only difference is kafka_version in Kafka cluster: 3.7.x and 3.7.x.kraft.
resource "aws_msk_cluster" "hm_amazon_msk_cluster" {
  cluster_name           = var.amazon_msk_cluster_name
  kafka_version          = "3.7.x.kraft" # <- only this line is different, the other one is `3.7.x`
  number_of_broker_nodes = var.kafka_broker_number
  storage_mode           = "TIERED"
  broker_node_group_info {
    instance_type   = "kafka.m7g.large"
    security_groups = [var.amazon_vpc_security_group_id]
    client_subnets  = var.amazon_vpc_subnet_ids
  }
  logging_info {
    broker_logs {
      s3 {
        enabled = true
        bucket  = var.kafka_broker_log_s3_bucket_name
        prefix  = "brokers"
      }
    }
  }
  encryption_info {
    encryption_at_rest_kms_key_arn = var.aws_kms_key_arn
  }
  client_authentication {
    sasl {
      iam = true
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "hm_amazon_s3_object" {
  bucket = var.s3_bucket_name
  key    = var.s3_key
  source = var.local_file_path
  etag   = filemd5(var.local_file_path)
}

resource "aws_mskconnect_custom_plugin" "hm_amazon_msk_plugin" {
  name         = var.amazon_msk_plugin_name
  content_type = "ZIP"
  location {
    s3 {
      bucket_arn = var.s3_bucket_arn
      file_key   = var.amazon_msk_plugin_s3_key
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_mskconnect_connector" "my_amazon_msk_connector" {
  name                 = var.amazon_msk_connector_name
  kafkaconnect_version = "2.7.1"
  capacity {
    autoscaling {
      mcu_count        = 1
      min_worker_count = 1
      max_worker_count = 2
      scale_in_policy {
        cpu_utilization_percentage = 40
      }
      scale_out_policy {
        cpu_utilization_percentage = 95
      }
    }
  }
  # https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install#label-kafka-properties
  # https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-streaming-kafka
  connector_configuration = {
    "connector.class"                  = "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector"
    "tasks.max"                        = 4
    "topics"                           = var.kafka_topic_name
    "buffer.count.records"             = 10000
    "buffer.flush.time"                = 5
    "buffer.size.bytes"                = 20000000
    "snowflake.url.name"               = "xx.snowflakecomputing.com"
    "snowflake.user.name"              = var.snowflake_user_name
    "snowflake.private.key"            = var.snowflake_private_key
    "snowflake.private.key.passphrase" = var.snowflake_private_key_passphrase
    "snowflake.role.name"              = var.snowflake_role_name
    "snowflake.ingestion.method"       = "SNOWPIPE_STREAMING"
    "snowflake.enable.schematization"  = true
    "snowflake.database.name"          = var.snowflake_database_name
    "snowflake.schema.name"            = var.snowflake_schema_name
    "value.converter"                     = "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url" = var.confluent_schema_registry_url
    "errors.log.enable"                   = true
    "errors.tolerance"                    = "all"
    "jmx"                                 = true
  }
  kafka_cluster {
    apache_kafka_cluster {
      bootstrap_servers = var.amazon_msk_cluster_bootstrap_servers
      vpc {
        security_groups = [var.amazon_vpc_security_group_id]
        subnets         = var.amazon_vpc_subnet_ids
      }
    }
  }
  kafka_cluster_client_authentication {
    authentication_type = "IAM"
  }
  kafka_cluster_encryption_in_transit {
    encryption_type = "TLS"
  }
  plugin {
    custom_plugin {
      arn      = aws_mskconnect_custom_plugin.hm_amazon_msk_plugin.arn
      revision = aws_mskconnect_custom_plugin.hm_amazon_msk_plugin.latest_revision
    }
  }
  log_delivery {
    worker_log_delivery {
      s3 {
        bucket  = var.msk_log_s3_bucket_name
        prefix  = var.msk_log_s3_key
        enabled = true
      }
    }
  }
  service_execution_role_arn = var.amazon_msk_connector_iam_role_arn
}

Is there anything else I need pay attention to use Kafka KRaft mode? And could it be a MSK bug? Thanks!

Your kafka connect version says 2.7.1, so you're not using "3.7.x" classpath...? Besides, it's not recommended to run Kafka connect from the brokers, so then Kraft wouldn't matter. How are you configuring the plugin.path setting to pickup those jars?

Thanks @OneCricketeer , hmm that could be the reason. Yeah unfortunately seems MSK only allows Kafka Connect version 2.7.1 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect.html Even when users create the Kafka connector in the UI, the Apache Kafka Connect version is set to 2.7.1

Hi @OneCricketeer I added my Kafka plugin and connector Terraform code. Basically plugin is pointing to the ZIP file (jars inside) in the S3. And connector points to that plugin.

I've not configured msk connect myself, but assuming the connectors are distinct deployments, then Kraft shouldn't affect anything, since it wouldn't share any classpath or configs with Connect. So, if it works on one cluster, but not another, it seems like a bug to me

Got it, thanks @OneCricketeer! BTW, I can confirm even I force to change kafkaconnect_version = "3.7.0", it will throw Error: creating MSK Connect Connector (DevelopmentTrackerZooKeeperKafkaSinkConnector): BadRequestException: Invalid parameter kafkaConnectVersion: Unsupported KafkaConnectVersion [3.7.0]. Valid values: [2.7.1]. which means MSK only supports 2.7.1.

What folder is the image showing? Is that KAFKA_DIR/plugins/development-Tracker-kafka-sink-plugin.zip_inflated within the Connect worker?

@OneCricketeer Yeah, the raw file is development-tracker-zookeeper-kafka-sink-plugin.zip in S3, it got loaded to Kafka at KAFKA_DIR/plugins/development-tracker-kafka-sink-plugin.zip_inflated. (I updated the log a little bit, tracker is lowercase, I redact a word in the log and accidentally make T uppercase which is actually lowercase.)

Hmm this is a little awkward. After adding depends_on between each resources, it works well now for Kafka in KRaft mode. Nothing else changed.
I think because Terraform by default applies concurrently. Maybe when the Kafka connector started, the ZIP in S3 has not been fully uploaded yet.
resource "aws_s3_object" "hm_amazon_s3_object" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_mskconnect_custom_plugin" "hm_amazon_msk_plugin" {
  # ...
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_object.hm_amazon_s3_object
  ]
}

resource "aws_mskconnect_connector" "my_amazon_msk_connector" {
  # ...
  depends_on = [
    aws_mskconnect_custom_plugin.hm_amazon_msk_plugin
  ]
}

